# How to extend controller in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter, controller

How can I create my own *core controller* in **codeigniter 4** like **codeigniter 3**?
[image: Core Controller Codeigniter 3]

Answer (score 5):

When you say "core" controller I understand you to mean a "base" controller which in CI v3 is often named `MY_Controller`. If that is what you are asking for it's actually much easier in v4 because of namespaces and the autoloader. Also, there is no need for the trickery of using a prefix like `MY_`.

Here's just how easy it is. The "base" controller...

File: **/application/Controllers/Base.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Base extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
{
    //your code here
}
```

Then extend the above to create any other controller

File: **/application/Controllers/Home.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends \App\Controllers\Base
{
   // Your code here
}
```

The `Home` controller will inherit all the properties and methods you define in `Base`.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much @DFriend. I will try!!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to create another core controller, there is already a core controller provided, which is BaseController. 
You need to just extend it to your choice

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter 4, there are 3 ways by which you can extend Controllers as Parent controller before performing your operations.

> **1. Extend BaseController**

Spark Command

```
php spark make:controller Blog --suffix
```

It will generate Controller with this structure:

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Controllers;
    
    use App\Controllers\BaseController;
    
    class BlogController extends BaseController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

> **2. Extends from CodeIgniter\Controller instead of BaseController**

Spark Command

```
php spark make:controller Blog --suffix --bare
```

It will generate Controller with this structure:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> **3. Extends from a RESTful resource**

Spark Command

```
php spark make:controller Blog --suffix --restful
```

It will generate Controller with this structure:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class BlogController extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * Return an array of resource objects, themselves in array format
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Return the properties of a resource object
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show($id = null)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Return a new resource object, with default properties
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function new()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Create a new resource object, from "posted" parameters
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Return the editable properties of a resource object
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Add or update a model resource, from "posted" properties
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update($id = null)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Delete the designated resource object from the model
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I hope may be this will help you for something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php namespace App\Core;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Home extends Controller
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

see my codes

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Shared\Controllers;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 */


use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use Modules\Auth\Config\Services;
use Myth\Auth\AuthTrait;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use  Modules\Shared\Interfaces\UrlQueryParamInterface;
use  Modules\Shared\Libraries\UrlQueryParam;

class ApiController extends ResourceController
{
    use AuthTrait;

    protected $format = "";
    public object $userObject;
    public UrlQueryParamInterface $urlQueryParam;

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = [
        'cookie',
        'url',
        'from',
        'filesystem',
        'text',
        'shared'
    ];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */


    /**
     * @var string
     * Holds the session instance
     */
    protected $session;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->userObject = (object)[];
    }

    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);


        $this->urlQueryParam = new UrlQueryParam($request);

        $requestWithUser = Services::requestWithUser();
        $this->userObject = $requestWithUser->getUser();

    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Common\Controllers;


use Modules\Common\Config\Services;
use Modules\Common\Entities\AdvertisementEntity;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Modules\Shared\Controllers\ApiController;

class Advertisement extends ApiController
{


    /**
     * index function
     * @method : GET
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $advertisementEntity = new AdvertisementEntity();
        $this->urlQueryParam->dataMap($advertisementEntity->getDataMap());

        $advertisementService = Services::advertisementService();
        $findAllData = $advertisementService->index($this->urlQueryParam);


        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $findAllData['data'],
            'pager' => $findAllData['pager']
        ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_OK, lang('Shared.api.receive'));


    }

    /**
     * show function
     * @method : GET with params ID
     */
    public function show($id = null)
    {


        $advertisementService = Services::advertisementService();
        $findOneData = $advertisementService->show($id);

        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $findOneData['data'],
            'pager' => $findOneData['pager']
        ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_OK, lang('Shared.api.receive'));

    }

    /**
     * create function
     * @method : POST
     */
    public function create()
    {


        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
            'link' => 'required',


        ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules)) {

            return $this->respond([
                'error' => $this->validator->getErrors(),

            ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, lang('Shared.api.validation'));

        };


        $advertisementEntity = new AdvertisementEntity((array)$this->request->getVar());
        $advertisementEntity->enableStatus()->createdAt();
        $advertisementService = Services::advertisementService();
        $advertisementService->create($advertisementEntity);


        return $this->respond([
            'insertId' => $advertisementService->getInsertID()
        ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_CREATED, lang('Shared.api.save'));


    }

    /**
     * update function
     * @method : PUT or PATCH
     */
    public function update($id = null)
    {


        if ($this->request) {
            //get request from Vue Js
            $json = $this->request->getJSON();
            if (!isset($id)) {
                $id = $json->id;
            }


            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
                'link' => 'required',


            ];

            if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
                return $this->respond([
                    'error' => $this->validator->getErrors(),

                ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, lang('Shared.api.validation'));

            }


            $advertisementEntity = new AdvertisementEntity((array)$this->request->getVar());
            $advertisementEntity->updatedAt();

            $advertisementService = Services::advertisementService();
            $advertisementService->update($id, $advertisementEntity);


        }
        return $this->respond([
        ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_OK, lang('Shared.api.update'));


    }

    /**
     * edit function
     * @method : DELETE with params ID
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {

        $advertisementService = Services::advertisementService();
        $advertisementService->delete($id);

        return $this->respond([
        ], ResponseInterface::HTTP_OK, lang('Shared.api.remove'));


    }

}
```